# Filtering pyspark dataframe rows based on a column condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframe , and I want to select rows in the first dataframe which timestamp field is bigger ( more recent ) than the max (timestamp) of the second dataframe.
I tried this:

```
df1 = sqlContext.table("db.table1")   # FIRST DATAFRAME
max_timestamp = sqlContext.sql("select max(timestamp) as max from db.table2") # MAX TIMESTAMP IN THE SECOND DATAFRAME
df1.where(df1.timestamp > max_timestamp.max).show(10,False)
```

but it says:  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (with expected output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are comparing against a DataFrame `column` (max_timestamp.max) from another DataFrame. You need to either `collect` the result as a `String` or `crossJoin` as a new column to compare against.

#### Reproducible example

```
data1 = [("1", "2020-01-01 00:00:00"), ("2", "2020-02-01 23:59:59")]
data2 = [("1", "2020-01-15 00:00:00"), ("2", "2020-01-16 23:59:59")]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["id", "timestamp"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["id", "timestamp"])
```

#### collect as String

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max
max_timestamp = df2.select(max(col("timestamp")).alias("max")).distinct().collect()[0][0]
max_timestamp
# '2020-01-16 23:59:59'
df1.where(col("timestamp") > max_timestamp).show(10, truncate=False)
# +---+-------------------+
# |id |timestamp          |
# +---+-------------------+
# |2  |2020-02-01 23:59:59|
# +---+-------------------+
```

#### crossJoin as new column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max
intermediate = (
    df2.
        agg(max(col("timestamp")).alias("start_date_filter"))
)
intermediate.show(1, truncate=False)
# +-------------------+                                                           
# |start_date_filter  |
# +-------------------+
# |2020-01-16 23:59:59|
# +-------------------+
(
    df1.
        crossJoin(intermediate).
        where(col("timestamp") > col("start_date_filter")).
        show(10, truncate=False)
)
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
# |id |timestamp          |start_date_filter  |
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
# |2  |2020-02-01 23:59:59|2020-01-16 23:59:59|
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
```